# UWP, What is the correct syntax for a storyboard to access a path in a controltemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP windows 10 phone app and having trouble getting a storyboard to rotatetransform a path defined inside a buttons controltemplate.

I would prefer to acheive this in xaml. Do i specify for storyboard.targetproperty a quazi xaml path? => viewer.navbutton.PART_Arrow?

```
<Grid x:Name="layoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="ShowNav">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="navigation.(FrameworkElement.Height)" Value="Auto"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="HideNav">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="navigation.(FrameworkElement.Height)" Value="0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="rotateStoryBoard">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotateDownArrow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                            From="0"
                            To="90"
                            Duration="0:0:2"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="navigation">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="navbar" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="refresh_Copy"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Content="Refresh"
            Click="refresh_Click"
            RenderTransformOrigin="1.457,0.562" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="viewer">
        <Button x:Name="navButton"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                Click="navButton_Click">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Path x:Name="PART_Circle"
                                          Fill="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                          Stroke="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
                                          StrokeThickness="1.5" 
                                          Data="M0,0 A30,30 0 0 0 60,0"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="PART_Arrow" 
                                          Stroke="GreenYellow" 
                                          StrokeThickness="1.5" 
                                          Data="M12,6 L30,18 L48,6">
                                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateDownArrow" 
                                                             Angle="0"
                                                             CenterX="30"
                                                             CenterY="12"/>
                                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                                    </Path>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>

                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
        <WebView x:Name="Web"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 NavigationCompleted="Web_NavigationCompleted"
                 ScriptNotify="Web_OnScriptNotify"
                 Canvas.ZIndex="0"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct syntax for a storyboard to access a path in a controltemplate?

The `Path` control you want to access is inside a [`ControlTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.controltemplate). According to the XAML name scopes in templates section of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namescopes):

> Templates in XAML provide the ability to reuse and reapply content in a straightforward way, but templates might also include elements with names defined at the template level. That same template might be used multiple times in a page. For this reason, templates define their own XAML name scopes, independent of the containing page where the style or template is applied.

So the `ControlTemplate` has its own namescopes, you cannot directly access a control inside it by `Name`. You may need to use [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper) class to help you access the controls.

But if you want a storyboard can access the control, you can let the storyboard in a same template with the control and they will be in a same scope.

In additionally, `Button` [control template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx) contains four default [VisualStates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.VisualState), trigger the storyboard by one visual state may be recommended. The following code put the storyboard into the ControlTemplate and it is triggered when the button is pressed that you can reference.

```
<Grid
    x:Name="layoutRoot"
    Padding="50"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   ...
    <Grid x:Name="viewer" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button
            x:Name="navButton"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Canvas.ZIndex="1"
            Click="navButton_Click">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"> 
                                    <Grid.Resources>
                                        <Storyboard x:Name="rotateStoryBoard">
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                Duration="0:0:2"
                                                From="0"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="rotateDownArrow"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                To="90" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </Grid.Resources>
                                    <Path
                                        x:Name="PART_Circle"
                                        Fill="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                        Stroke="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                        StrokeThickness="1.5"
                                        Data="M0,0 A30,30 0 0 0 60,0" />
                                    <Path
                                        x:Name="PART_Arrow"
                                        Stroke="GreenYellow"
                                        StrokeThickness="1.5"
                                        Data="M12,6 L30,18 L48,6">
                                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateDownArrow" Angle="0" CenterX="30" CenterY="12" />
                                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                                    </Path>
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                        Duration="0:0:2"
                                                        From="0"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="rotateDownArrow"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                                        To="90" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState> 
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
...
</Grid>
```